# Conditional replacement of values in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the spark dataframe below:

```
+----------+-------------+--------------+------------+----------+-------------------+
|      part|      company|       country|        city|     price|               date|
+----------+-------------+--------------+------------+----------+-------------------+
| 52125-136|  Brainsphere|          null|       Braga|   493.94€|2016-05-10 11:13:43|
| 70253-307|Chatterbridge|         Spain|   Barcelona|   969.29€|2016-05-10 13:06:30|
| 50563-113|     Kanoodle|         Japan|     Niihama| ¥72909.95|2016-05-10 13:11:57|
|52380-1102|    Flipstorm|        France|    Nanterre|   794.84€|2016-05-10 13:19:12|
| 54473-578|  Twitterbeat|        France|      Annecy|   167.48€|2016-05-10 15:09:46|
| 76335-006|        Ntags|      Portugal|      Lisbon|   373.07€|2016-05-10 15:20:22|
| 49999-737|     Buzzbean|       Germany|  Düsseldorf|    861.2€|2016-05-10 15:21:51|
| 68233-011|    Flipstorm|        Greece|      Athens|   512.89€|2016-05-10 15:22:03|
| 36800-952|       Eimbee|        France|      Amiens|   219.74€|2016-05-10 21:22:46|
| 16714-295|      Teklist|          null|      Arnhem|    624.4€|2016-05-10 21:57:15|
| 42254-213|   Thoughtmix|      Portugal|     Amadora|   257.99€|2016-05-10 22:01:04|
```

From these columns, only the country column has null values. So what I want to do is to fill the null values with the country that corresponds to the city on the right. The dataframe is big and there are cases where Braga (for example) has the country that it belongs and other cases where this is not the case.

So, how can I fill those null values in the country column based on the city column on the right and at the same time take advantage of Spark's parallel computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window functions for that.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window


df.withColumn(
    "country",
    F.coalesce(
        F.col("country"),
        F.first("country").over(Window.partitionBy("city").orderBy("city")),
    ),
).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **`coalesce`** function in spark to get first `non null` value from list of columns.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+--------+---------+
#| country|     city|
#+--------+---------+
#|    null|    Braga|
#|   Spain|Barcelona|
#|    null|   Arnhem|
#|portugal|  Amadora|
#+--------+---------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("country",coalesce(col("country"),col("city"))).show()
#+--------+---------+
#| country|     city|
#+--------+---------+
#|   Braga|    Braga|
#|   Spain|Barcelona|
#|  Arnhem|   Arnhem|
#|portugal|  Amadora|
#+--------+---------+
```

Comment: @AlexandrosGiannakakis Does it really work ? you want the field country to be filled with the name of the city ? like `city=Braga and Country=Braga` ? not portugal ?

Comment: oh god. You are right. this just fills with the name of the city. Really sorry for that!!